# .__repr__() help python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a class definition for a playing Card. A playing card needs to store information about its suit (clubs, diamonds, hearts, or spades) and rank (2-10, jack, queen, king, or ace).  My next step, which is creating a `.__repr__()` method, is giving me trouble.  I know that it will be similar to my `.__str__` method, but the `__repr__` method still gives me trouble.  This is what I have so far:

```
class Card:
"""a class for determining suit and rank of a card in a 52-card deck

attributes: suit(x) and rank(y)"""
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        """assigns values to the appropriate attributes

        str, str -> str"""
        self.x = rank
        self.y = suit
    def __str__(self):
        """creates a str for appropriate display of cards"""
        if not isinstance(self.x,int):
            if self.x == "J" or self.x == "j":
                x = "Jack"
            elif self.x == "Q" or self.x == "q":
                x = "Queen"
            elif self.x == "K" or self.x == "k":
                x = "King"
            elif self.x == "A" or self.x == "a":
            x = "Ace"
        else:
            x = str(self.x)

        if self.y == "D" or self.x == "d":
            y == "Diamonds"
        elif self.y == "H" or self.x == "h":
            y == "Hearts"
        elif self.y == "S" or self.x == "s":
            y == "Spades"
        elif self.y == "C" or self.x == "c":
            y == "Clubs"
        return x + " of " + y

    def __repr__(self):
        """returns a str that could be used as a command by python"""
        return self.x + 'of' + self.y
```

Comment: is there a specific reason your redefining str and repr instead of just using a deck and card class

Comment: just following instructions... @JGreenwell

Comment: What is the problem with your current `__repr__` method exactly? If I do `q_hearts = Card('H', 'Q'); print(q_hearts); print(repr(q_hearts))` I get "Queen of Hearts" and "QofH", what do you want the repr to be?

Comment: nothing wrong with `__repr__`just if there are easier methods when the option exists :)

Comment: not sure what trouble `__repr__` is giving you.

Comment: How about using appropriate instance attribute names as instructed, `self.rank` and `self.suit` are *way* more readable than `x` and `y`

Answer (score 3):

For the `repr` that could be used as a Python expression, well, it should return a string having format `Card('D', 'J')`, with `repr` of the `self.suit` and `self.rank` respectively (fixed their names for you!) into their `repr` representation.

This is easy by using the `%` formatting operator:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Card(%r, %r)' % (self.suit, self.rank)
```

Now

```
print(repr(Card('D', 9)))
```

will output

```
Card('D', 9)
```

---

On a related note, instead of testing the given suit and rank for both lower and upper case letters, just convert them to upper case in your constructor:

```
if isinstance(rank, str):
    self.rank = rank.upper()
else:
    self.rank = rank

self.suit = suit.upper()
```

Now you just need to test for their upper case variants. Though I'd never recommend mixing `int` and `str` for such value; either number the cards 1-13 or 2-14 or so, or use strings for all ranks.